# Linq to CSV select by column

Tags: linq

If I have the following (sample) text file;

```
year,2008,2009,2010
income,1000,1500,2000
dividends,100,200,300
net profit,1100,1700,2300
expenses,500,600,500
profit,600,1100,1800
```

Is there a way in Linq that I can select the expenses for 2010 only?

So far I have the following which gets me all the data;

```
        var data = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
            .Select( 
                l => {
                    var split = l.CsvSplit();
                    return split;
                }
            );

        foreach (var item in data)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: ${1}", item[0], item[1]);
```

Comment: @Ani the Select will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, and from his usage in the foreach it appears that T is `string[]`

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst: Yes, I should have said `IEnumerable<string[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's always the 3rd value column, then

```
// the expenses row
var query = data.Single(d => d[0] == "expenses");

// the third column
return query[3];
```

and if you don't, then

```
var columnNumber = Array.IndexOf(data.First(), "2010");
return query[columnNumber];
```

Comment: I didn't exactly use this approach but it did point me in the right direction thank you @Kirk.

Comment: @griegs Sorry, used to the List / Linq syntax.  I've updated it now to use `Array.IndexOf` which should work.

Answer (score 1):

See LINQtoCSV, its a library that does all this for you. I've used it, and it works like a charm.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx